# Problems with CATALINA_PID and ARTIFACTORY_PID while upgrading Artifactory to the latest version

Tags: tomcat8, artifactory

While upgrading my Artifactory server (free OSS version) from the version 5.2.0 to the latest 5.4.5, I was hit by an ARTIFACTORY_PID problem.
After migrating from 5.3.2 to 5.4.0, the Artifactory server did not want to start anymore complaining about

> PID file /var/opt/jfrog/run/artifactory.pid not readable (yet?) after start.

I found the only way around it is to remove the line `export CATALINA_PID=$ARTIFACTORY_PID` from the `setenv.sh` of the tomcat.

Note that upgrade from 5.2.0 to 5.3.2 went smoothly.

However, after upgrading from 5.4.0 to the latest 5.4.5 this trick does not work anymore. Now I get an error:

> Job for artifactory.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status artifactory.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

And when executing `service artifactory status`, I get:

```
● artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: resources) since Tue 2017-07-25 09:40:10 CEST; 4s ago
  Process: 31912 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 25 09:40:10 linux systemd[1]: Failed to start Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine.
Jul 25 09:40:10 linux systemd[1]: Unit artifactory.service entered failed state.
Jul 25 09:40:10 linux systemd[1]: artifactory.service failed.
```

In fact Artifactory is now running showing version 5.4.5, but I am not happy about all those errors above.

Plus I am a bit failing to understand the purpose of CATALINA_PID and/or ARTIFACTORY_PID. Why the tomcat was failing on the startup because of this file? What was wrong with the permissions? I think I did no extra actions before.

The only difference that before it was installed from an official downloaded rpm. But now using an official remote yum repo.

If I try to create an empty /var/opt/jfrog/run/artifactory.pid file, while Artifactory is running, it gets deleted. Who is deleting this file and why? Is it a standard tomcat behavior?

OS: CentOS 7, up to date.

Comment: I appear to have similar symptoms, I am using puppet to start the script on 18.04β and if I let puppet start the service via systemd, it does not create the pid, but if I run the artifactoryManage.sh it will create the pid.

Answer (score 7):

In my case (in a slow virtual machine) the error message from the command `artifactoryManage.sh start` was:

> ERROR: Artifactory Tomcat server did not start in 60 seconds. Please check the logs

The log file told that the only problem was slowness (/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs/artifactory.log):

> ### Artifactory successfully started (64.802 seconds)   ###

The problem was solved by adding a longer timeout to the service definition at /etc/systemd/system/artifactory.service:

```
[Service]
Environment=START_TMO=120
```

After editing the service definition, as you know, `systemctl daemon-reload` was needed.

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, your settings in `/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/` may be corrupted. Fortunately I had a backup and I was able to recover it.

Answer (score 5):

Run this script:

```
/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start
```

It will show the exact error to you.

In my case it was java version not updated. So I updated to java 1.8.