# Artifactory issue (maybe Derby related)

Tags: derby, artifactory

A few days back I noticed that my artifactory instance was not running anymore. Now I am not able to start it again. In the localhost logs in `/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/logs` I found a long stack trace, but I am not sure whether that is the actual problem because It seems to appear already at a time where everything was still working fine.

Update 2 weeks later: A few days after initially writing this question, artifactory was suddenly running again. I did not understand why, since nothing I tried seemed to help. Now, the same issue is back...

The localhost log:

```
19-Jul-2018 10:50:34.781 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Using artifactory.home at '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory' resolved from: System property
19-Jul-2018 10:50:38.843 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
19-Jul-2018 10:51:57.405 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Using artifactory.home at '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory' resolved from: System property
19-Jul-2018 10:52:03.598 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
19-Jul-2018 10:53:07.428 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Using artifactory.home at '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory' resolved from: System property
19-Jul-2018 10:53:15.436 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
19-Jul-2018 10:53:32.409 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Could't establish connection with db: jdbc:derby:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby;create=true
        at org.jfrog.config.db.TemporaryDBChannel.<init>(TemporaryDBChannel.java:35)
        at org.artifactory.common.ArtifactoryConfigurationAdapter.getDbChannel(ArtifactoryConfigurationAdapter.java:183)
        at org.jfrog.config.wrappers.ConfigurationManagerImpl.getDBChannel(ConfigurationManagerImpl.java:422)
        at org.artifactory.config.MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.dbChannel(MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.java:206)
        at org.artifactory.config.MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.tryToCreateTable(MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.java:95)
        at org.artifactory.config.MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.validateOrInsertKeyInformation(MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.java:65)
        at org.artifactory.config.MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.handleMasterKey(MasterKeyBootstrapUtil.java:46)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigManagers.initHomes(BasicConfigManagers.java:95)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigManagers.initialize(BasicConfigManagers.java:81)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.contextInitialized(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby' with class loader java.net.URLClassLoader@e9e54c2, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.jfrog.config.db.TemporaryDBChannel.<init>(TemporaryDBChannel.java:31)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby' with class loader java.net.URLClassLoader@e9e54c2, see the next exception for details.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.RawStore.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.access.RAMAccessManager.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.startModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.bootServiceModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.bootStore(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.db.BasicDatabase.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.boot(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.TopService.bootModule(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startProviderService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.findProviderAndStartService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startPersistentService(Unknown Source)
        ... 29 more
19-Jul-2018 10:53:32.503 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifactory home not initialized
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener.initArtifactoryHome(LogbackConfigListener.java:55)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.logback.LogbackConfigListener.contextInitialized(LogbackConfigListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19-Jul-2018 10:53:32.569 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Artifactory home not initialized.
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.getArtifactoryHome(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:176)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.setSessionTrackingMode(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:150)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.contextInitialized(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19-Jul-2018 10:54:44.743 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
19-Jul-2018 10:56:21.997 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log jolokia: No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
19-Jul-2018 17:22:06.575 INFO [localhost-startStop-5] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19-Jul-2018 17:24:22.721 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Using artifactory.home at '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory' resolved from: System property
19-Jul-2018 17:24:27.463 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
19-Jul-2018 17:26:29.617 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

artifactory.log with severall restart attempts. Note: it always gets stuck at '[art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:281) -'

```
    /  \   _ __| |_ _| |_ __ _  ___| |_ ___  _ __ _   _  | |  | | (___| (___
   / /\ \ | '__| __| |  _/ _` |/ __| __/ _ \| '__| | | | | |  | |\___ \\___ \
  / ____ \| |  | |_| | || (_| | (__| || (_) | |  | |_| | | |__| |____) |___) |
 /_/    \_\_|   \__|_|_| \__,_|\___|\__\___/|_|   \__, |  \____/|_____/_____/
 Version:  5.9.0                                   __/ |
 Revision: 50900900                               |___/
 Artifactory Home: '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory'

2018-08-01 16:52:01,039 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.a.f.l.ArtifactoryLockFile:65) - Found existing lock file. Artifactory was not shutdown properly. [/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/.lock]
2018-08-01 16:52:03,744 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:484) - Artifactory application context set to NOT READY by refresh
2018-08-01 16:52:03,777 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:227) - Refreshing artifactory: startup date [Wed Aug 01 16:52:03 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-01 16:53:29,163 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:217) - Database: Apache Derby 10.11.1.1 - (1616546). Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.11.1.1 - (1616546) Pool: derby
2018-08-01 16:53:29,178 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.d.DbServiceImpl:220) - Connection URL: jdbc:derby:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby
2018-08-01 16:54:05,176 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'blob' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/artifactory-storage-db-5.9.0.jar!/
2018-08-01 16:54:05,524 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.b.p.t.BinaryProviderClassScanner:76) - Added 'empty, external-file, external-wrapper, file-system, cache-fs, retry' from jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory/WEB-INF/lib/binary-store-core-2.0.37.jar!/
2018-08-01 16:54:49,865 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactorySchedulerFactoryBean:647) - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2018-08-01 16:54:52,478 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:234) - Artifactory context starting up 39 Spring Beans...
2018-08-01 16:55:04,519 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:356) - Initialzed new service id: jfrt@01c72726yd871j0wqyck0k0n0z
2018-08-01 16:55:05,338 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.j.s.c.EncryptionWrapperFactory:33) - createArtifactoryKeyWrapper  EncryptionWrapperBase{ encodingType=ARTIFACTORY_MASTER, topEncrypter=BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='DESede',  keyId='22QC5'}, formatUsed=OldFormat, decrypters=[BytesEncrypterBase{ Cipher='DESede',  keyId='22QC5'}]}
2018-08-01 16:55:05,687 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:556) - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8040/access (bundled) source: detected
2018-08-01 16:55:09,887 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:279) - Waiting for access server...
2018-08-01 16:56:49,406 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:281) -
                _   _  __           _                      ____   _____ _____
     /\        | | (_)/ _|         | |                    / __ \ / ____/ ____|
    /  \   _ __| |_ _| |_ __ _  ___| |_ ___  _ __ _   _  | |  | | (___| (___
   / /\ \ | '__| __| |  _/ _` |/ __| __/ _ \| '__| | | | | |  | |\___ \\___ \
  / ____ \| |  | |_| | || (_| | (__| || (_) | |  | |_| | | |__| |____) |___) |
 /_/    \_\_|   \__|_|_| \__,_|\___|\__\___/|_|   \__, |  \____/|_____/_____/
 Version:  5.9.0                                   __/ |
 Revision: 50900900                               |___/
 Artifactory Home: '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory'

2018-08-01 16:56:49,510 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.a.f.l.ArtifactoryLockFile:65) - Found existing lock file. Artifactory was not shutdown properly. [/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/.lock]
2018-08-01 16:56:52,853 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:484) - Artifactory application context set to NOT READY by refresh
2018-08-01 16:56:52,908 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:227) - Refreshing artifactory: startup date [Wed Aug 01 16:56:52 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-01 17:00:01,718 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:281) -
                _   _  __           _                      ____   _____ _____
     /\        | | (_)/ _|         | |                    / __ \ / ____/ ____|
    /  \   _ __| |_ _| |_ __ _  ___| |_ ___  _ __ _   _  | |  | | (___| (___
   / /\ \ | '__| __| |  _/ _` |/ __| __/ _ \| '__| | | | | |  | |\___ \\___ \
  / ____ \| |  | |_| | || (_| | (__| || (_) | |  | |_| | | |__| |____) |___) |
 /_/    \_\_|   \__|_|_| \__,_|\___|\__\___/|_|   \__, |  \____/|_____/_____/
 Version:  5.9.0                                   __/ |
 Revision: 50900900                               |___/
 Artifactory Home: '/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory'

2018-08-01 17:00:01,827 [art-init] [WARN ] (o.a.f.l.ArtifactoryLockFile:65) - Found existing lock file. Artifactory was not shutdown properly. [/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/.lock]
2018-08-01 17:00:04,617 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:484) - Artifactory application context set to NOT READY by refresh
2018-08-01 17:00:04,619 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:227) - Refreshing artifactory: startup date [Wed Aug 01 17:00:04 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-01 17:03:09,821 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:281) -
```

When I try to start the service via `systemctl start artifactory.service` it fails with "`Job for artifactory.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status artifactory.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`".

Output `systemctl status artifactory.service`:

```
nikl@nikls-droplet-1:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/logs$ sudo systemctl status artifactory.service
● artifactory.service - Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-07-20 23:19:14 UTC; 25min ago
   Process: 18829 ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Jul 20 23:18:23 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[18829]: /usr/bin/java
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[18829]: Starting Artifactory tomcat as user artifactory...
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 su[18851]: Successful su for artifactory by root
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 su[18851]: + ??? root:artifactory
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 su[18851]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[18829]: Max number of open files: 1024
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[18829]: Using ARTIFACTORY_HOME: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[18829]: Using ARTIFACTORY_PID: /var/opt/jfrog/run/artifactory.pid
Jul 20 23:18:24 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[18829]: Tomcat started.
Jul 20 23:19:14 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine.
```

Output `journalctl -xe`:

```
nikl@nikls-droplet-1:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/logs$ sudo journalctl -xe
-- Kernel start-up required KERNEL_USEC microseconds.
--
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
--
-- Userspace start-up required 108849 microseconds.
Jul 20 23:54:42 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1001.
-- Subject: Unit user@1001.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user@1001.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 20 23:54:42 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19282]: Max number of open files: 1024
Jul 20 23:54:42 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19282]: Using ARTIFACTORY_HOME: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
Jul 20 23:54:42 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19282]: Using ARTIFACTORY_PID: /var/opt/jfrog/run/artifactory.pid
Jul 20 23:54:42 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19282]: Tomcat started.
Jul 20 23:54:42 nikls-droplet-1 su[19305]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Jul 20 23:56:11 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul 20 23:56:11 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine.
-- Subject: Unit artifactory.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit artifactory.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 20 23:56:11 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 20 23:56:11 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul 20 23:56:11 nikls-droplet-1 polkitd(authority=local)[1443]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:19273:10938586 (system bus name :1.317, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jul 20 23:56:16 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 20 23:56:16 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Stopped Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine.
-- Subject: Unit artifactory.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit artifactory.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 20 23:56:16 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Starting Setup Systemd script for Artifactory in Tomcat Servlet Engine...
-- Subject: Unit artifactory.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit artifactory.service has begun starting up.
Jul 20 23:56:16 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19863]: /usr/bin/java
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19863]: Starting Artifactory tomcat as user artifactory...
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 su[19885]: Successful su for artifactory by root
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 su[19885]: + ??? root:artifactory
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 su[19885]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user artifactory by (uid=0)
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 systemd-logind[1395]: New session c140 of user artifactory.
-- Subject: A new session c140 has been created for user artifactory
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- A new session with the ID c140 has been created for the user artifactory.
--
-- The leading process of the session is 19885.
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 systemd[1]: Started Session c140 of user artifactory.
-- Subject: Unit session-c140.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-c140.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19863]: Max number of open files: 1024
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19863]: Using ARTIFACTORY_HOME: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19863]: Using ARTIFACTORY_PID: /var/opt/jfrog/run/artifactory.pid
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 artifactoryManage.sh[19863]: Tomcat started.
Jul 20 23:56:17 nikls-droplet-1 su[19885]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user artifactory
Jul 20 23:56:18 nikls-droplet-1 systemd-logind[1395]: Removed session c140.
-- Subject: Session c140 has been terminated
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Documentation: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
--
-- A session with the ID c140 has been terminated.
```

I have tried deleting the .lck files in the derby folder because that seems to have solved the "`Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby`" issue for someone else before, but nothing changed for me. After the next start of artifactory the files were just back and the same error showed up in the log files.

Since the output of `systemctl start artifactory.service` complaints about a timeout I raised `START_TMO` in `artifactory.default` to 300, but still the same problem persists. I also raised `START_TMO` in a different file according to the first answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297704/problems-with-catalina-pid-and-artifactory-pid-while-upgrading-artifactory-to-th).

I don't understand what is going on and would be very grateful for any help/advice.

Comment: Same problem for me

Comment: Me as well... :(