# Job for artifactory.service failed

Tags: devops, artifactory

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I just installed oss version if JFrog Artifactory
To run artifactory I used `systemctl start artifactory.service` by getting this error:

```
Job for artifactory.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status artifactory.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

If I run `systemctl status artifactory.service` this is what I am getting

```
● artifactory.service - Artifactory service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jun 01 00:25:42 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Jun 01 00:25:42 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting Artifactory service...
Jun 01 00:25:43 siddharth-HP-Notebook artifactoryManage.sh[17274]: 2020-05-31T18:55:43.286Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifac>
Jun 01 00:25:43 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Can't open PID file /run/artifactory.pid (yet?) >
Jun 01 00:25:43 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Jun 01 00:25:43 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start Artifactory service.
Jun 01 00:25:48 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Stopped Artifactory service.
Jun 01 00:25:48 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service:10: PIDFile= references a pat>
Jun 01 00:31:37 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service:10: PIDFile= references a pat>
Jun 01 00:31:38 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service:10: PIDFile= references a pat>
```

Also during the installation, I got this error in the end that can be helpful:

```
Triggering migration script, this will migrate if needed ...
chown: invalid user: ‘artifactory:artifactory’
[WARN] Could not set owner of [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc] to [artifactory:artifactory]
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.1) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that PID file is there:
`Jun 01 00:25:43 siddharth-HP-Notebook systemd[1]: artifactory.service: Can't open PID file /run/artifactory.pid (yet?) >`

If it's there, you need to check permissions and your service file to check what's your path of PID file

Comment: I checked the folder and PID file is missing from there. What should I do?

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297704/problems-with-catalina-pid-and-artifactory-pid-while-upgrading-artifactory-to-th I don't know how artifactory works.

Comment: did you ever found the solution to this problem i got the same