# artifactory timeout in browser

Tags: artifactory, connection-timeout

I installed artifactory as instructed in https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-jfrog-artifactory-on-ubuntu-linux/

I systematically get a timeout in the browser when opening the URL HTTP://mysite:8081/artifactory. And yet:

- HTTP://mysite:8080 is working, showing Jenkins
- In the artifactory-service.log file, I see references to 8081 port, such as:

```
2022-02-17T10:17:45.264Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [eb828abcd130c42b] [ctoryContextConfigListener:272] 
[art-init ] - Artifactory (jfrt) service initialization completed in 44.085 seconds. 
Listening on port: 8081
```

or

```
artifactory.local.port.for.replicator    | 8081
```

The command `systemctl list-unit-files` gives lines:

```
artifactory.disabled.service           generated       enabled
artifactory.service                    enabled         enabled
```

When I do `systemctl status artifactory.service` I get

```
fvila@SL1RDAPP3414:~$ systemctl status artifactory.service
● artifactory.service - Artifactory service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/artifactory.service; enabled; vendor p>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-02-17 12:19:36 CET; 3h 48min ago
   Main PID: 6568 (java)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 2274)
     Memory: 844.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/artifactory.service
             ‣ 6568 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/third-party/java/bin/java -Djava>
```

I found existing posts relative to similar situations here:
[Job for artifactory.service failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121223/job-for-artifactory-service-failed)
That page suggests looking into artifactory.pid. Someone asked what to do if they had no such file (I don't either), there's a link to

[Problems with CATALINA_PID and ARTIFACTORY_PID while upgrading Artifactory to the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297704/problems-with-catalina-pid-and-artifactory-pid-while-upgrading-artifactory-to-th)

which suggests running `artifactoryManage.sh start` . I don't have that file either...

Comment: which artifactory version is this? I believe it is version 7.x, can you try to access the Artifactory via HTTP://mysite:8082/ui

Comment: @MuhammedKashif the file I downloaded is jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.33.12-linux.tar.gz 
However, HTTP://mysite:8082/ui  also gives a timeout

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed jfrog artifactory on a separate VM (not the same as jenkins) and it works now.

Comment: so it was an issue with port conflict I assume

Comment: Today I had the same problem again with the separate VM and this time I solved it by putting HTTP instead of https. So maybe that was the problem to begin with.